# Testing joining list with a 60MB string with `timeit` causes MemoryError

Tags: python, timeit

My test appends creates a list containing a 60MB string and a 5-byte string. This list is then joined with `join()`:

```
import timeit
setup_str = 'str_5byte = "\xfa\xea\x02\x02\x02"; L = [str_5byte]; str_60mb = str_5byte * 12000000'
t = timeit.Timer('L.append(str_60mb); str_long = "".join(L)', setup=setup_str)
t.timeit(100)
```

Returns this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python25\lib\timeit.py", line 161, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
MemoryError
```

I assume that after every execution the variables are deleted and garbage-collected, so why am I running out of memory? Running the test with 8 executions is OK, but higher than that and I get this error.

Comment: I'm guessing the values are *not* actually deleted/garbage-collected.

Comment: @WayneWerner You're right, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) GC is off by default. But surely the variables (i.e. `L`) should be deleted after every execution, otherwise? If not, I suppose I should add `del L` though this affects the timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with `t.timeit` the setup statement is executed only once and then the test statement multiple times. This means the list `L` persists and grows every iteration, resulting obviously in your system running out of memory.

Try `min(t.repeat(repeat=100, number=1))` to execute the setup each time before the evaluation of the test statement.

[Here's the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#python-interface) if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

on a quick experiment, I'm pretty sure `setup` does exactly the opposite of what you expect - it's run before *every* call. So you get an extra 60 mb each time through, which does not get collected. When I move that setup code directly into the test code, I am able to run.

Comment: But according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit): "[`Timer.timeit`] executes the setup statement once".